# Method-Chaining in C#

Tags: c#

I have actually no idea of what this is called in C#.
But i want to add the functionallity to my class to add multiple items at the same time.

```
myObj.AddItem(mItem).AddItem(mItem2).AddItem(mItem3);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2055701/5558126 Gives a good example how to implement this

Answer (score 131, accepted):

The technique you mention is called chainable methods. It is commonly used when creating DSLs or [fluent interfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) in C#.

The typical pattern is to have your AddItem() method return an instance of the class (or interface) it is part of. This allows subsequent calls to be chained to it.

```
public MyCollection AddItem( MyItem item )
{
   // internal logic...

   return this;
}
```

Some alternatives to method chaining, for adding items to a collection, include:

Using the `params` syntax to allow multiple items to be passed to your method as an array. Useful when you want to hide the array creation and provide a variable argument syntax to your methods:

```
public void AddItems( params MyItem[] items )
{
    foreach( var item in items )
        m_innerCollection.Add( item );
}

// can be called with any number of arguments...
coll.AddItems( first, second, third );
coll.AddItems( first, second, third, fourth, fifth );
```

Providing an overload of type IEnumerable or IEnumerable so that multiple items can be passed together to your collection class.

```
public void AddItems( IEnumerable<MyClass> items )
{
    foreach( var item in items )
         m_innerCollection.Add( item );
}
```

Use .NET 3.5 collection initializer syntax. You class must provide a single parameter `Add( item )` method, implement IEnumerable, and must have a default constructor (or you must call a specific constructor in the initialization statement). Then you can write:

```
var myColl = new MyCollection { first, second, third, ... };
```

Comment: +1 learnt new things :D i thought that i hava to make a different method for chaning method

Answer (score 34):

Use this trick:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private List<MyItem> _Items = new List<MyItem> ();

    public MyClass AddItem (MyItem item)
    {
        // Add the object
        if (item != null)
            _Items.Add (item)

        return this;
    }
}
```

It returns the current instance which will allow you to chain method calls (thus adding multiple objects "at the same time".

Answer (score 20):

> "I have actually no idea of what this is called in c#"

A fluent API; `StringBuilder` is the most common .NET example:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
string s = sb.Append("this").Append(' ').Append("is a ").Append("silly way to")
     .AppendLine("append strings").ToString();
```

Answer (score 12):

Others have answered in terms of straight method chaining, but if you're using C# 3.0 you might be interested in *collection initializers*... they're only available when you make a constructor call, and only if your type has appropriate `Add` methods and implements `IEnumerable`, but then you can do:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass { item1, item2, item3 };
```

Answer (score 6):

You could add an extension method to support this, provided your class inherits from ICollection:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void CanChainStrings()
    {
        ICollection<string> strings = new List<string>();

        strings.AddItem("Another").AddItem("String");

        Assert.AreEqual(2, strings.Count);
    }
}
```

```
public static class ChainAdd
{
    public static ICollection<T> AddItem<T>(this ICollection<T> collection, T item)
    {
        collection.Add(item);
        return collection;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you use the [`params`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx) keyword?

```
public void AddItem (params MyClass[] object)
{
    // Add the multiple items
}
```

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
AddItem(ICollection<Item> items);
```

or

```
AddItem(params Item[] items);
```

You can use them like this

```
myObj.AddItem(new Item[] { item1, item2, item3 });
myObj.AddItem(item1, item2, item3);
```

This is not method chaining, but it adds multiple items to your object in one call.

Answer (score 1):

If your item is acting as a list, you may want to implement an interface like iList or iEnumerable / iEnumerable.

Regardless, the key to chaining calls like you want to is returning the object you want.

```
public Class Foo
{
   public Foo AddItem(Foo object)
   {
        //Add object to your collection internally
        return this;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
class MyCollection
{
    public MyCollection AddItem(Object item)
    {
        // do stuff
        return this;
    }
}
```