# How to implement method chaining?

Tags: c#, methods, chaining

In C# how does one implement the ability to chain methods in one's custom classes so one can write something like this:

```
myclass.DoSomething().DosomethingElse(x);
```

etc...

Thanks!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119799/method-chaining-in-c

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Chaining is a good solution to produce new instance from existing instances:

```
public class MyInt
{
    private readonly int value;

    public MyInt(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public MyInt Add(int x) {
        return new MyInt(this.value + x);
    }
    public MyInt Subtract(int x) {
        return new MyInt(this.value - x);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
MyInt x = new MyInt(10).Add(5).Subtract(7);
```

---

You can also use this pattern to modify an existing instance, but this is generally not recommended:

```
public class MyInt
{
    private int value;

    public MyInt(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public MyInt Add(int x) {
        this.value += x;
        return this;
    }
    public MyInt Subtract(int x) {
        this.value -= x;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
MyInt x = new MyInt(10).Add(5).Subtract(7);
```

Comment: +1 For the good example. Generally this concept is referred to as a Fluent Interface - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface. Though technically you aren't using one, but it would be trivial to introduce one.

Answer (score 1):

DoSomething should return a class instance with the DoSomethingElse method.

Answer (score 1):

For a mutable class, something like

```
class MyClass
{
    public MyClass DoSomething()
    {
       ....
       return this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your methods should return `this` or a reference to another (possibly new) object depending on exactly what you want to acheive