# Calling method vs assigning object to method AND void return type vs object return type

Tags: c#, object, inheritance, methods, reference

Apologies for the really bad title, but I wasn't quite sure how to phrase it any better. I'm creating a fairly simple program just to play around with inheritance in C#, involving dealing cards to players. I was wondering what the best approach is, and what the difference is, between these two ways of assigning a hand to a player:

In the Player class:

```
public Player takeHand(List<Card> cards)
{
    this.hand = cards;
    return this;
}
```

And then within the "House" class (i.e. dealer/main class), loop through players and deal out cards:

```
List<Player> players = new List<Player>() {new Player.. new Player..};
List<List<Card>> hands;

for (int i = 0; i < players.count; i++)
{
    hands.Add(new List<Card>());
    for (int j = 0; j < cardsToDeal; j++)
    {
        hands[i].Add(dealCard());
    }
    players[i].takeHand(hands[i]); // correct?
    players[i] = players[i].takeHand(hands[i]); // correct?
}
```

My first question is which is the correct way of calling the method 'takeHand'? They both seem to work identically.

My second question, is what is the difference in then making the "takeHand" method instead have a 'void' return, and then not returning 'this'? i.e:

```
public void takeHand(List<Card> cards)
{
    this.hand = cards;
}
```

and then doing:

```
players[i].takeHand(hands[i]);
```

It still seems to work as I'd expect, and assigns the cards to players correctly.

Thanks for any comments/advice!
FYP

Comment: About the second part, it's only useful to leave `return this` if you plan on using [method-chaining](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119799/method-chaining-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is useless : `players[i] = players[i].takeHand(hands[i]);`: You don't need to modify the player but just their `hand`. The correct for is:

```
public void takeHand(List<Card> cards)
{
    this.hand = cards;
}
```

---

Because, IRL, when you deals the card, you don't change the whole player right? You just change the card they have in theirs hands.

This is the same here, you don't need to change `player[i]` each time you deal. Furthermore, you're returning `this` which is like writing *I replace Jack with Jack*

Comment: Great, thanks - I thought this was the case but I seem to tend to always end up using "void" return types for a lot of my methods which feels un-object-oriented.