# What is the significance of returning TodoService in addTodo and deleteTodoById methods in Todo CRUD app in sitepoint tutorial

Tags: angular

with reference [todo app of sitepoint tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/angular-2-tutorial/) If I remove the return type `TodoDataService` from `addTodo`  and `deleteTodoById` the app functions the same. Then what is the significance of using return type as `TodoDataService` in `addTodo`  and `deleteTodoById`

Comment: Best practice is to type _everything_. Making sure your accessor is expecting the same output as your return value simply prevents errors later on and allows most IDE to catch errors before compilation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from the comments, there are two questions here:

> 1. Why are the `addTodo` and `deleteTodoById` functions annotated with a return type of `TodoDataService`, given that Typescript is also
>      happy if they are not provided?

TypeScript is rather clever. It can infer that the return type is `TodoDataService`, given that the code for both functions returns a `TodoDataService` instance. If you and I were to read the code, we could come to the same conclusion. However, *explicitly annotating* the return type is our way of telling TypeScript that the return type **must** be `TodoDataService`.

So, in the case where we do not have the annotation, it would be perfectly fine to remove the `return this` line. Note that TypeScript would now infer that the return type is `void`, as we're no longer returning a value.

When using the explicit annotation, if we remove the `return this` line, TypeScript will complain. In this case, we've told it that a `TodoDataService` **must** be returned, yet we have failed to return anything at all.

> 2. Why do both the `addTodo` and `deleteTodoById` functions belonging to `TodoDataService` return the `TodoDataService` itself?

This is an example of [Method Chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119799/method-chaining-in-c-sharp). The basic *idea* here is to make the code look a little bit cleaner. For example, if you wanted to add two `Todo`s and remove one, you could write:

```
todoDataService.addTodo(...);
todoDataService.addTodo(...);
todoDataService.deleteTodoById(...);
```

Using method chaining (i.e. by returning the service from the functions), you could instead write:

```
todoDataService
    .addTodo(...)
    .addTodo(...);
    .deleteTodoById(...);
```

In the tutorial you've referenced, there is no reason for the `return this` line. Although I haven't had chance to read through the full details of the article, I cannot see anywhere that method chaining is actually used with `TodoDataService`.