# C#: calling non static member function without creating object

Tags: c#

While going through a codebase, I ran into a statement similar to the following:

```
new Class().MemberFunction();
```

What is this statement actually doing? Is it calling the member function without creating an object of this class?

Comment: It is the same as `Class myInstance = new Class(); myInstance.MemberFunction();`, except it does not use an variable. The `new` *creates* the object/instance; and in both cases the [member] method call is invoked upon *an expression that Evaluates to an Instance*. This is the same reason why `AMethodReturningAnObjectOfClassThatMightBeNewOrReused().MemberFunction()` "works": the member is invoked on an *expression* of the appropriate `Class`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Method-Chaining in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119799/method-chaining-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is creating a new instance of `Class` - as you can clearly see the `new Class()` part of the code - the only thing that's not "usual" about it is that it doesn't store the reference to that instance, but just use it to call the `MemberFunction();`.

This means that whoever wanted to execute the `MemberFunction()` did not need to keep the reference to the specific instance (which in turn, might mean that the `MemberFunction()` should be converted to a static method, but there's not enough information to know for sure).

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new class ( because of 'new' )
2. Launch MemberFunction() which you called

it means, it doesn't work what you actually wanted.

even static already creates class once.

Comment: "even static already creates class once." What? calling a static member guarantees type initialization, but most certainly does not create an instance of the type...