# C++: calling non-static member function without instance of object

Tags: c++, open-source

I'm looking at the source code for the Godot game engine, and came across the following (some omitted for simplicity):

```
// popup_menu.cpp

int PopupMenu::_get_mouse_over(double x) const
{
    if (x >= get_size().width)
        return -1;
    // ...
}


// control.cpp

Size2 Control::get_size() const
{
    return data.size_cache;
}
```

Why is it legal to call the method `get_size()` without first instantiating an object of type `Control` and then invoking its member function? I tried to recreate this behavior in my own file, but it would not compile as I would normally expect:

```
class Control
{
public:
    double get_size() const;
};

double Control::get_size() const
{
    return 5.0;
}

class PopupMenu
{
public:
    int _get_mouse_over(double d) const;
};

int PopupMenu::_get_mouse_over(double d) const
{
    return d > get_size(); // compile error, as expected
}
```

What could be causing this behavior? If you are interested, the actual source code for each of these methods can be found at:

line 110:
https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/master/scene/gui/popup_menu.cpp

line 1770:
https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/master/scene/gui/control.cpp

I searched for this question and found [C#: calling non static member function without creating object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53095766/c-calling-non-static-member-function-without-creating-object) which does not answer my question, since in his case there actually was an instance that the method was being invoked through (and it's a different language).

Comment: Does PopupMenu derive from Control?

Comment: @immibis Yes, it does. `class Popup : public Control`, `class PopupMenu : public Popup`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Becuase `PopupMenu` derives from `Control`, every instance of `PopupMenu` is also an instance of `Control`.

When a member function of `PopupMenu` calls `get_size()`, it calls Control's `get_size()` function on itself.

Or stated differently, `PopupMenu` has a `get_size()` function because it is derived from `Control`.

In your recreation, `PopupMenu` doesn't derive from `Control` so this does not apply.