# Is there any way to set properties to an existing control less verbosely?

Tags: c#

For example, there is an existing button named B.

If I want to change some property of it, I have to do it like this:

```
B.FontSize=15;
B.Width=100;
B.Height=100;
B.Padding=new Thickness(5);
```

and so on.

It is so troublesome that I have code `B.` when every time I set it.

Is there any way that it can be simplified like MAU in MAUI (however, neither WPF nor Winforms can do it like this), just like:

```
B.FontSize(15).Width(100).Height(100).Padding(new Thickness(5));
```

Comment: If you make extension methods, sure, but you'd have to make the extension methods.

Comment: @gunr2171 Well, I'm just not sure if C# has similar syntax natively.

Comment: The common term would be ["Fluent" or "method chaining"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119799/method-chaining-in-c-sharp). It's something that the framework you're working with would need to support. MAUI does it. WPF and WinForms just rely on regular properties. You can add your own if you'd like, but it would mean mirroring all the properties as extension methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript many people call it "method chaining" from the jQuery days where it was made popular, in C# we tend to call it the "builder" pattern which is how the Fluent stuff is crafted.

```
public static class ControlExtensions
{
    public static T SetFontSize<T>(this T control, double fontSize) where T : Control
    {
        control.FontSize = fontSize;
        return control;
    }

    public static T SetWidth<T>(this T control, double width) where T : Control
    {
        control.Width = width;
        return control;
    }

    public static T SetHeight<T>(this T control, double height) where T : Control
    {
        control.Height = height;
        return control;
    }

    public static T SetPadding<T>(this T control, Thickness padding) where T : Control
    {
        control.Padding = padding;
        return control;
    }
}
```

Examples:

```
Button button = new Button().SetFontSize(15).SetWidth(100).SetHeight(100).SetPadding(new Thickness(5));

TextBox textBox = new TextBox().SetFontSize(15).SetWidth(100).SetHeight(100).SetPadding(new Thickness(5));
```

PS: There is this built-in VB support using the `with` keyword, it's like this but I haven't seen a C# equivalent.

```
With B
.Height = 15
.FontSize = 12
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Another practical way is to create your custom button and use it anywhere consistently without setting its common properties every time:

```
public class CustomButton : System.Windows.Controls.Button
{
    public CustomButton()
    {
        FontSize = 15;
        Width = 100;
        Height = 100;
        Padding = new Thickness(5);
        // Other custom properties
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't about setting properties on a *new* instance of a control - it's about changing properties on an *existing* instance.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Certainly agree. My actual aim is to *encourage* the OP to approach the problem from a different angle. I don't believe using extension methods and object initializers ease setting properties *too much* with regard to syntax. On the other hand, if the OP uses different values each time he sets the properties then my solution is not viable of course.